# Shortlist plugin item title not showing

Tags: entries, plugin-shortlist

I've been getting annoyed at one small problem I can't solve with the Craft Shortlist Plugin. It seems that I have got everything to work but no matter what I do, the {{ item.title }} just won't display the entry title that was added the list the default list.
All the functionality seems to be working no problem but I just simply can't get the item title to appear.

### Code Used to display my list

```
{% set lists = craft.shortlist.lists %}

{% if lists is empty %}
    <p>You have no lists at the moment.</p>
{% else %}

{% for list in lists %}
    <h1>{{ list.title }}</h1>

    {% if list.items is empty %}
        <p>This list is empty</p>
    {% else %}

        <ul>
            {% for item in list.items %}
                <p>{{ item.title }}</p>
            <li>
                <a href="{{ item.removeActionUrl }}">remove</a>
                {{ item.id }} <strong>{{ item.title }}</strong>
            </li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>

    {% endif %}

{% endfor %}

{% endif %}
```

### Code used to give my entries add and remove buttons

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('locations') %}
  {% set item = craft.shortlist.item(entry.id) %}
  <h2>{{ entry.title }}</h2>

  {% if item.inList %}
      <a href="{{ item.removeActionUrl }}">Remove from Favourites</a>
  {% else %}
      <a href="{{ item.addActionUrl }}">Add to Favourites</a>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Would really appreaciate the help on this one so let me know if more detail is needed.

Comment: What happens when you try `{{ item.element.title }}`

Comment: Legend! I spent hours trying to get this to work but never tried that! Thanks so much